# How to load an image to java application assets folder

Tags: java, java-web-start, nifty-gui

I'm going to make a java application with nifty-gui[[1]](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nifty-gui/) using java web start

When user click on upload image, a file chooser is showed (FileOpenService)

After that, image should be visible in image control.

Unfortunately, nifty-gui can use images only from assets.

How to download this image into asset? Maybe there is a way to modify actual image using data from FileContent class?

Comment: What is "nifty-gui"?  Is that a tool/API or are you just saying your GUI is nifty?  Is it [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nifty-gui/)?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I've in mind the API, your link is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution, created after discussion [[1]](http://jmonkeyengine.org/groups/general/forum/topic/how-to-display-image-from-local-computer-in-nifty-gui-with-java-web-start/#post-174482)

```
assetManager.registerLoader(AWTLoader.class, "jpg");
assetManager.registerLocator("/", FileLocator.class);
            image(new ImageBuilder() {{
                filename("/home/marek/photo2.jpg");
            }});
```